# Two identical implementations of the same approach, why one is much faster than the other?

Tags: c++, arrays, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to solve [this question](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/). My solution is almost identical to the fastest one. But for a test case, I have **time limit exceeded** while the other (the fastest one) does not. Could anybody explain for me why my code is so slow?. Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) {
        int M = grid.size();
        if(M == 0) return 0;
        int N = grid[0].size();
        if(N == 0) return 0;
        int flag = 2;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j){
                if(grid[i][j] == '1'){
                    //breadth-first search from here
                    flag++;
                    count++;
                    queue<pair<int, int>> nodes;
                    grid[i][j] = flag;
                    nodes.push({i,j});
                    while(!nodes.empty()){
                        auto node = nodes.front();
                        nodes.pop();
                        if(node.first > 0 && grid[node.first-1][node.second] == '1'){
                            grid[node.first-1][node.second] = flag;
                            nodes.push(make_pair(node.first-1, node.second));
                        }
                        if(node.first < M-1 && grid[node.first+1][node.second] == '1'){
                            grid[node.first+1][node.second] = flag;
                            nodes.push(make_pair(node.first+1, node.second));
                        }
                        if(node.second > 0 && grid[node.first][node.second-1] == '1'){
                            grid[node.first][node.second-1] = flag;
                            nodes.push(make_pair(node.first, node.second-1));
                        }
                        if(node.second < N-1 && grid[node.first][node.second + 1] == '1'){
                            grid[node.first][node.second+1] = flag;
                            nodes.push(make_pair(node.first, node.second+1));
                        }                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

Here is the fastest solution. The author was very clever to use the array offsets, and I think that's the only difference between his code and mine. But I don't think it speed up the code.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) {
        int m = grid.size(), n = m ? grid[0].size() : 0, islands = 0, offsets[] = {0, 1, 0, -1, 0};
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == '1') {
                    islands++;
                    grid[i][j] = '0';
                    queue<pair<int, int>> todo;
                    todo.push({i, j});
                    while (!todo.empty()) {
                        pair<int, int> p = todo.front();
                        todo.pop();
                        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                            int r = p.first + offsets[k], c = p.second + offsets[k + 1];
                            if (r >= 0 && r < m && c >= 0 && c < n && grid[r][c] == '1') {
                                grid[r][c] = '0';
                                todo.push({r, c});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return islands;
    }
};
```

Comment: Unconditional `if` statements in your code that refer to `vector`, only one in the faster solution.  And maybe *barely* the second code passed the test.  You don't know if the second code came close to being unaccepted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this can't be it. The fastest solution unrolls to 4 ifs as well.

Comment: I see something, if the amount of Islands gets to be at least the asci value of `1`, I think your code enter in an infinity cycle. The issue is that you're writing on the grid the value of flag, and if is equal to `'1'`, then...

Comment: *My solution is almost identical to the fastest one.* -- Then I am assuming your solution *is* a solution, only slow?  Or is the code wrong?  Why not take both codes, test data, and run it on your local compiler to see what the issue is?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the OP specified he/she gets a tle on a test case

Comment: *But for a test case* -- What is the test case?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie usually this competition sites have hidden test cases. The OP should confirm or show the failing test case.

Comment: Yes, but I believe leetcode *does* show you the test case that failed.  It's up to the OP to take both code samples, get the test case, and run it for themselves on a local compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no, they don't, because otherwise you could just hard code the answers for the test case inputs

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I think my solution is correct, only one last test case, too long to paste it here, that I had tle.

Comment: So again, why not take your code, the other persons code, the test case, and locally, create your own run and see if there is an issue?  Why do you need to paste the code here, when you can readily run the code and test case yourself?   If there is no issue, then the second code would complete with an answer, and your code would complete (albeit slower) with the same answer.  Out of all the online judge site questions we get here, this is one where you could do all of the work yourself (you have both code, and test case).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks. I didn't realize that my code was wrong until Eduardo pointed out. I thought it was correct, it was just slow. And I didn't understand why it was slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are overwriting the islands on grid with the value of flag. When the value of flag gets equal to `'1'`, then your code enters an infinite cycle because you are asking for cell with `'1'` for detecting islands.

With this extra line change on your code I got accepted on the problem.

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) {
        int M = grid.size();
        if(M == 0) return 0;
        int N = grid[0].size();
        if(N == 0) return 0;
        int flag = 2;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j){
                if(grid[i][j] == '1'){
                    //breadth-first search from here
                    flag++;
                    if (flag == '1') flag++;              /////THIS LINE HERE
                    count++;
                    queue<pair<int, int>> nodes;
                    grid[i][j] = flag;
                    nodes.push({i,j});
                    while(!nodes.empty()){
                        auto node = nodes.front();
                        nodes.pop();
                        if(node.first > 0 && grid[node.first-1][node.second] == '1'){
                            grid[node.first-1][node.second] = flag;
                            nodes.push(make_pair(node.first-1, node.second));
                        }
                        if(node.first < M-1 && grid[node.first+1][node.second] == '1'){
                            grid[node.first+1][node.second] = flag;
                            nodes.push(make_pair(node.first+1, node.second));
                        }
                        if(node.second > 0 && grid[node.first][node.second-1] == '1'){
                            grid[node.first][node.second-1] = flag;
                            nodes.push(make_pair(node.first, node.second-1));
                        }
                        if(node.second < N-1 && grid[node.first][node.second + 1] == '1'){
                            grid[node.first][node.second+1] = flag;
                            nodes.push(make_pair(node.first, node.second+1));
                        }                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

Note: This code was only for ilustrate the error, that doesn't mean that is an elegant solution for the bug.

Comment: Thanks, I'm well aware of this problem, and I initialized the flag at 2. It keeps increasing, so it can never be 1.

Comment: @qsp The character `1` doesn't have integer value 1, its asci value is greater. I think it really is 49. Initialize your flag with (the character) '2' and submit the problem again

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thanks a lot. You are right. I still wonder why after your fix, it is faster than only 20% of the submissions, while the other is faster than 99%. I wonder if there is any other inefficiency in the code.

Comment: Do all of the submissions use C++?  What are the compile options used for the C++ code?  Is the code running with optimizations turned on (since a vector is usually slower with no optimizations)?  If you don't know, then those percentage numbers are almost impossible to determine as to why they are what they are.